# Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI) SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to restore my data. But it's not working because of this error:

> Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

Then, I try to google it and try to restore by this way

```
RESTORE DATABASE Db_Database 
FROM DISK = N'D:\vto24112015.bak'
```

But I get these errors:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
>   The media family on device 'D:\vto24112015.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

What can I do to fix it? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Generally I see this when attempting to restore a SQL 2012 DB on a SQL 2008 server. If that isn't the case your bak might be bad?